# Why (or when) did Ctrl+[ stop working as a way type the ESC control code in Windows Command Processor (cmd.exe)?

Tags: cmd.exe, control-characters, conhost

I have a virtual machine with an up-to-date Windows 11 (`ver` reports *Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1555]*). When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> in a Windows Command Processor (`cmd.exe`) session nothing happens.

When I revert to the clean install snapshot of the VM (where `ver` reports *Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.525]*) pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> types the `ESC` control character (rendered as `^[` by Windows Command Processor).

The same is true for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to type `TAB` (rendered as `^I`). Other combinations (such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) still work.

Did one of the many changes I made to my Windows installation perhaps disable this feature, or was it disabled by an update?

Edit:

I noticed that disabling the Console Window Host option *Enable Ctrl key shortcuts* does enable the use of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to type `LF`, but does not enable the use of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> to type `ESC`.

Also, the observed behaviour is the same for a session hosted by Console Window Host (`conhost.exe`) and Windows Terminal (`wt.exe`).

Comment: I'm on `10.0.22621.1555`. Typing `Ctrl-[` into `cmd.exe` inserts `^[` as expected.

Comment: Thanks for checking, I've updated to 10.0.22621.1555 and it still does not work. It seems I may have made some changes to my system that now prevent this from working.